# Como alterar a cor da div sem afetar o :hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estou tentando alterar a cor do meu header assim que ele passa de 400px porem ao fazer isso o meu :hover não funciona mais na div apos descer a barra

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < 400) { 
    $('.color').css({
      'background-color': 'black' 
    });    
    $('.sub-menu a').css({      
      'color': 'white',      
    });        

  } else {
    $('.color').css({
      'background-color': 'white'
    });    
    $('.sub-menu a').css({
      'color': 'black'
    });          
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {    
    width: 100%;
    height: 200%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 60px;
}
.color {
    background-color: black;   
    transition: 0.6s;    
}
.sub-menu {
    height: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}
.sub-menu ul{
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.sub-menu ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
}
.aqui {
    height: fit-content;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}
.sub-menu a {
    font-size: 17px;    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    padding-right: 30px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.6s;
}

.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: orangered;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html lang="pt">

<head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./main.css">
</head>

<body>    
    <header class="color" >
        <div class="logo-radical"></div>
        <div class="sub-menu">
            <ul>
                <il>
                    <a >Home</a>
                </il>
                <il>
                    <a >Programacões</a>
                </il>
                <il>
                    <a >Times</a>
                </il>
                <il>
                    <a >Contato</a>
                </il>
            </ul>
        </div>               
    </header>
    <div class="aqui" id="aqui">
        <span>Aqui !</span>
            
    </div> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu vi dois problemas no seu código. O Primeiro é no jQuery onde vc está colocando estilos CSS diretamente na tag usando o método `.css()` quando vc coloca o estilo direto na tag vc não consegue sobrescreve-lo facilmente pelo estilos que estão na sua classe CSS, tipo `.classe {color: black}` não vai sobrescrever `<div class="classe" style="color: red">` Ela vai continuar `red` e não `black`.

Outro detalhe é a lógica que vc usou no jQuery e no CSS, vc está colocando muita força no classe, vc pode ler sobre isso nesse artigo do Maujor https://www.maujor.com/tutorial/specificity_wars.php então para fazer a classe "pegar" vc tem que ter uma força maior na classe, tipo `.color .sub-menu ul li a:hover` é mais forte que `.color .sub-menu a:hover`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E no jQuery para facilitar te sugiro criar uma *classe de ativação*, é um classe que vc vai colocar na `div pai`, de forma que se o pai tiver essa classe os filhos vão se comporta de uma forma, e se o pai não tiver essa classe os filhos vão se comporta de outra forma... No seu caso a classe normal do pai é `.color` e com a ativação fica `.color.roll`, sendo que a classe `.roll` é a *classe de ativação* adicionada pelo jQuery no *scroll*

Veja o código da imagem acima.

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
 if ($(document).scrollTop() > 400) {
  $(".color").addClass("roll");
 } else {
  $(".color").removeClass("roll");
 }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 200%;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 height: 60px;
}

.color {
 background-color: black;
 transition: 0.6s;
}

.sub-menu {
 height: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 float: left;
}

.sub-menu ul {
 margin-top: 20px;
}

.sub-menu ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 list-style: none;
}

.aqui {
 height: fit-content;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: red;
 z-index: 0;
 position: absolute;
 top: 400px;
 width: 100%;
}

.sub-menu a {
 font-size: 17px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: white;
 padding-right: 30px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: 0.6s;
}

.color .sub-menu ul li a:hover {
 color: orangered;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

.color.roll {
 background-color: white;
}

.color.roll .sub-menu a {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<header class="color">
  <div class="logo-radical"></div>
  <div class="sub-menu">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Programacões</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Times</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a>Contato</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<div class="aqui" id="aqui">
  <span>Aqui !</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ótimo, muito bem explicado. Obrigado

Comment: @Wingeds sem problemas jovem, que bom que vc leu a explicação, isso que faz a diferença! []´s

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo tudo bem? Tente usar !important na frente da cor do hover, eu testei e deu certo. espero que te ajude.

```
.sub-menu a:hover {
    color: orangered !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Lembrando que sua tag `<li>` está escrito `<il>`. Tente isso:

```
.sub-menu ul > li a:hover {
    color: orangered !important;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: Colocar !important funcionou tambem ! Obrigado